# how to disable required message for specific components at primefaces

Tags: validation, primefaces

I have many inputBox and their fields at primefaces.I need to show some of required message of inputBox and disable some of them. How I can disable some inputBox's requiredMessages(It should still go on being required without showing requiredMessage).

Regards
Alper

Answer (score 0):

p:growl globalOnly=true solved my problem